# Anchor Platform Set up Error

Tags: anchor

I'm trying to install the anchor platform following the current guide via:

https://developers.stellar.org/docs/anchoring-assets/anchor-platform/installation

However after I create the platform database and exit the running container, running "docker compose up" does not create a successful connection to the database as described in the docs. I get the following output:

$ docker compose up

[+] Running 0/1
⠿ platform-server Error                                                                            10.1s
Error response from daemon: manifest for stellar/anchor-platform:2.0.0-rc.1 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by using the latest docker image and not the 2.0.0-rc.1 release indicated in the developer docs.